# Deploying a simple HttpServlet to TomEE from the command line

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, command-line, apache-tomee

I'm trying to deploy a really simple HttpServlet to TomEE 1.7.2 using the command line but I'm having no luck. The code looks like this:

```java
@WebServlet("/HttpServlet")
public class SimpleHttpServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { 
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

I compile the class using the following command:

```bash
javac -cp "$TOMEE/lib/*" SimpleHttpServlet.java
```

All looks good as I only get the following warning:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6' less than -source '1.8'
1 warning
```

To create the war I do the following:

```bash
jar cf SimpleHttpServlet.war SimpleHttpServlet.class
```

I start TomEE using `bin/startup.sh` and deploy my war with:

```bash
bin/tomee.sh deploy path/to/my/SimpleHttpServlet.war
```

I get the following output:

```
deploying /.../SimpleHttpServlet.war
Nov 05, 2015 5:39:50 PM org.apache.openejb.client.EventLogger log
INFO: RemoteInitialContextCreated{providerUri=http://localhost:8080/tomee/ejb}
Application deployed successfully at "/.../SimpleHttpServlet.war"
App(id=/.../apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/apps/SimpleHttpServlet)
    EjbJar(id=SimpleHttpServlet, path=/.../apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/apps/SimpleHttpServlet)
    WebApp(context-root=/SimpleHttpServlet, id=SimpleHttpServlet, path=/.../apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2/apps/SimpleHttpServlet)
```

If I go to http://localhost:8080/manager/html I can see my war and everything looks okay. However, when I go to http://localhost:8080/SimpleHttpServlet/HttpServlet I get a 404 from TomEE:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SimpleHttpServlet/HttpServlet/
type Status report
message /SimpleHttpServlet/HttpServlet/
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.62 (1.7.2)
```

From what I understand, the `web.xml` is not mandatory when `@WebServlet` is used. What have I missed?

Thanks!

nyg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout of your [war file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) is incorrect. The class file of your servlet is now in `/` but must be in `/WEB-INF/classes`.